# how to get Python nltk recursive descent parser to recognize two phrases in a list

Tags: python, nltk

I want to get a recursive descent parser implemented using Python nltk to recognize two distinct phrases recognized by a grammar that occur in a single list of constituents, but it seems that the parser is only able to handle lists that contain one phrase recognized by the grammar. Is there a way to get it to recognize two phrases in the same list?

```
import nltk

constituent_list = ["200", "mg", "of", "dnp"]
cfg_string = """
DosageP -> num amount_unit prep substance
num -> '200' | '300'
amount_unit -> 'mg'
prep -> 'of'
substance -> 'dnp' | 'aspirin'
"""
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring(cfg_string)
rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)
for tree1 in rd_parser.parse(constituent_list):
    print(tree1)
```

output:

```
(DosageP (num 200) (amount_unit mg) (prep of) (substance dnp))
```

(as expected)

output with

```
constituent_list = ["200", "mg", "of", "dnp", "300", "mg", "of", "aspirin"]
```

instead: nothing

expected:

```
(DosageP (num 200) (amount_unit mg) (prep of) (substance dnp))
(DosageP (num 300) (amount_unit mg) (prep of) (substance aspirin))
```

It seems to work adding `S -> DosageP` and `S -> DosageP DosageP`.